# CSS PIE - border issue?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, css3pie

Facing issue while rendering RGBA color for border. RGBA color for border radius working fine but not border color and it is not showing any border color.

Is there any separate "-pie-" tag in CSSPie for use of RGBA in borders?

### My Code:

```
.border{
position:absolute; 
right: 250px; 
top: 250px; 
width: 400px; height:100px; 
z-index: 9999;
border: 3px solid rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.3);
border-radius: 10px; -moz-border-radius: 10px; 
behavior: url(PIE.htc); 
}
```

---

Not able to see the border in IE 7 & 8... Can you help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I personally have never gotten PIE to work in IE8 or any other IE for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not (yet) supported in PIE. If/when it does get implemented, it will undoubtedly require a separate -pie-border or -pie-border-color property, because IE's parser will throw away the entire border value if it contains the unrecognized rgba string.

Here is the ticket tracking this feature: https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues/55

Answer (score 2):

For `Border-radius` issue you have to apply the styles `position:relative; and z-index:0;` for that element. Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess is that IE7 and IE8 only support `rgb()` and not `rgba()`, and that would be why the border was not showing.